# Marketing Cloud ProperCase Workaround needed or Recommendations

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have some  logic in our email templates to Propercase peoples Salutation however have found where a person has a apostrophe in their name it drops that second letter to a lower case Eg: M’Silver becomes M’silver. Is there a work around for this?

We have some ampscript in the template already for the Saltation as per below so has to be compatible with that.

```
SET @prefCorrespondenceName = IsNullDefault(Preferred_Correspondence_Name, "")
SET @prefName = IsNullDefault(Preferred_Name, "")
SET @firstName = IsNullDefault([First Name], "")

IF @prefCorrespondenceName == !" THEN SET @Greeting = ProperCase(Trim(@prefCorrespondenceName))
ELSEIF @prefCorName != "" THEN SET @Greeting = ProperCase(Trim(@prefName)) 
ELSEIF @prefName != "" THEN SET @Greeting = ProperCase(Trim(@prefName)) 
ELSE 
 SET @Greeting = ProperCase(Trim(@firstName)) 
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will convert all your scenarios but if I were you, my idea would be:

- Split the name into smaller parts by `'` character
- ProperCase each part
- Do loop and concatenate each part with `'` character

```
%%[
    VAR @Greeting
    SET @prefCorrespondenceName = "MiKE  O'NeIL"

    IF @prefCorrespondenceName != "" THEN
        SET @rows = BuildRowSetFromString(@prefCorrespondenceName, "'")
        SET @rowCount = rowCount(@rows)
        IF @rowCount > 0 THEN
            for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
            VAR @name
            SET @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
            SET @name = field(@row,1)
            SET @name = ProperCase(Trim(@name))
            IF @i == 2 THEN
                SET @Greeting = CONCAT(@Greeting, "'",  @name)
            ELSE
                SET @Greeting = CONCAT(@Greeting, @name)
            ENDIF
        NEXT @i
        ELSE
            SET @Greeting = ProperCase(Trim(@prefCorrespondenceName))
        ENDIF

    ELSEIF @prefName != "" THEN 
        /* Do the same like the first check condition above */
    ELSE 
        /* Do the same like the first check condition above */
    ENDIF

]%% 
Hello %%=v(@Greeting)=%%
/*Output: Hello Mike O'Neil */
```

References:

- [BuildRowSetFromString](https://ampscript.guide/buildrowsetfromstring/) function
- [Process Loop](https://ampscript.guide/process-loops/)

Comment: Thanks this worked a treat, there was one thing I didn't take into a account is not only M'Silver but how would i adapt this for also check and correct where their Preferred Correspondence name is Mike O'Neil , i tried editing your script however I'm not very good at Ampscript so couldn't get it to work

Comment: @Jonnydolittle I have updated my answer. IMHO this way seems cumbersome and I think the data should be cleaned from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks very much, working perfectly, yes long term agree we need to clean up our data however this is will be a great interim fix